# Navigate to Url or Url.Action in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

This may have already been answered somewhere but I cannot find any information that makes sense to me.

I have a **Cancel** button in my **cshtml** that contains a **href='@Url.Action("Index")**.  It looks like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index")' class="linkbutton" id="btnCancel" title="Return to Home Page">Cancel</a>
```

Now, if changes have been made, I need to confirm whether to leave the page or save changes before leaving.

So, I've added an event on the button click to present a popup to confirm to continue or save.  Of course, leaving the button code in the cshtml file as it is, acts exactly as one would expect.  It's a link and my event never fires.

I changed the cshtml button to the following code:

```
<input type="button" class="navigationButtons" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" title="Return to Home Page" />
```

Now, my event gets fired and I display my popup to confirm continue or save. 
 The save works great because it's another method that performs a save to the db.  **I can't make the Confirm button into a link button**, because it is used in another place in the code that just continues without leaving the page.

I have found answers for **window.location**, **$.get** and **$.ajax**.  But I cannot figure out how to put into the JavaScript code that will go to my Index page.

PLEASE!  Does anyone know how to do this and help me understand what I obviously do not know.  :-(

Comment: Just handle the links `.click()` event, display your popup, and if its cancelled, then cancel the default action of the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your JavaScript is included in your `.cshtml` file, you can write Razor code inside your script:

```
window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Index")');
```

If you're having trouble with that, you could try creating a `hidden` link on your page and having your JavaScript trigger a click:

```
<a id="my-hidden-url" href="@Url.Action("Index")" hidden></a>

<script>
    $('#my-hidden-url').trigger('click');
</script>
```

Comment: The JavaScript is a separate file.  I'm not sure this will work for me unless I change my strategy.

Comment: If you want to keep your JS separate, you don't have to use the `Url Helper.` If you're confident that the URL will stay stable, you could hardcode it in the `replace()` function.

Comment: Perhaps I need to learn how to use window.location.replace, because it's doing the same thing everything else I tried.  Nothing!  I'm looking into it.  :-\

Comment: @Patricia I've edited my answer to include an extra solution that could also solve your issue.